How does the delayElements Operator work in Reactor Mono
I am working with Reactor Mono and I would like to understand the behavior of the delayElements operator.
From my understanding, the delayElements operator is used to introduce a delay between the emission of items. However, I am curious about how this delay is implemented and managed internally. Specifically, I have a few questions:
Scheduler Usage: Does the delayElements operator use a specific Scheduler to manage the delay? If so, which Scheduler is used and how does it handle the delay?
Thread Blocking: During the delay period, is the thread that is executing the delayElements operator blocked, or is it handled asynchronously? How does Reactor ensure that the delay does not block the thread?
Concurrency: If I use delayElements with a Flux that emits multiple items, how does Reactor manage the delays for each item? Is each delay handled independently, or is there a single Scheduler managing delays for all items?
Documentation: Can you provide references or examples from the official Reactor documentation or other resources that explain the internals of how delayElements operates?
I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations on these aspects. Thank you!
What is expected from Schedulers.parallel() threads as work, how do threads behave during termination, delay time?
